# Magento 2. How does Magento bypass the circular dependency for Magento\Backend\Model\Url?

Tags: magento2

Magento uses

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Url
```

as a preference for

```
Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
```

now `\Magento\Backend\Model\Url`
has a dependency on

```
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
```

which has a dependency on

```
\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
```

which in the admin area is implemented by

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session
```

which has a dependency on
`Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface`

which is implemented by

```
\Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver
```

which in turn has a dependency on

```
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
```

in the end what we have is a circular dependency

```
Backend\Model\Url <- depends -> FormKey
```

I've triple checked to see if a different implementation is provided for SidResolverInterface in the admin area, one that does not have a dependency on Magento\Framework\UrlInterface. This is not the case.

So how does Magento bypass this circular dependency, why does it not fail, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento bypasses this using Proxies. Both classes as specified as **Proxies** in `di.xml`

Excerpt from **vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Url">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeResolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Model\Url\ScopeResolver</argument>
            <argument name="authSession" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="formKey" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="scopeType" xsi:type="const">Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE</argument>
            <argument name="backendHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Helper\Data\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Excerpt from **base di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy" />
```